# Calculation for pay taxses by entereing monthly pay(exp. 3500 USD)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webforms

I have task to create some input (only number can be writen), and then when button is clicked  do some calculation (gross pay, federal taxses, payrate), then i need to put those values in view and write it to database.
Im pretty new in mvc or webform pages, so if anyone can help me? THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

You need a model that does your calculations and returns results of calculations

Have in your HTML code a form that asks for monthly pay:

```
<form asp-action="Calculate" method="post">
<label>Please enter your monthly pay to calculate:</label>
<input></input>
<button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

In your controller you need an action that takes the input as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Calculate(Float pay){
// check if input is valid
//call your calculate method on pay
return View(//your view, pass in result of calculation)
}
```